# How to check if an observable is of NEVER type?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a case in my angular application where I need to change the observable if the initial value was `NEVER`:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() isInitiallyOpen$?: Observable<boolean> = NEVER;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.isOpen$ = this.isInitiallyOpen$ ?? this.myService.isOpen$; // NOT WORKING
    // this.isOpen$ = NEVER at this point, and not this.myService.isOpen$
  }
}
```

I know that rxjs's `NEVER` is basically `new Observable<never>(noop())`. But my question is, is there any way to know that `isInitiallyOpen$` stream is actually holding a `NEVER` value?

Comment: `NEVER` !== `never`. Case matters.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure, but as an alternative you can use the `timeout`-operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [NEVER](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/never.ts) Observable at the GitHub project you can see that its basically an empty Observable with a noop function:

> `export const NEVER = new Observable<never>(noop)`

Therefore you can check if the variable equals `NEVER`. Below I made some tests for you to work with.

```js
const { NEVER, Observable, noop } = rxjs;

const foo$ = NEVER
const bar$ = NEVER

console.log("foo$ === bar$: ", foo$ === bar$) // true
console.log("foo$ === NEVER: ", foo$ === NEVER) // true
console.log("foo$ === Observable: ", foo$ === Observable) // false
console.log("foo$ === new Observable(): ", foo$ === new Observable()) // false
console.log("foo$ === Observable(() => {}): ", foo$ === new Observable(() => {})) // false
console.log("foo$ === Observable(noop): ", foo$ === new Observable(noop)) // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```